# como puedo navegar en una tabla html usando parent de jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tengo un problema que se me presentó recientemente. Necesito el valor de un `input` que se encuentra en una tabla en la segunda fila al presionar un button que se encuentra en la tercera fila, usando `jquery` y `parent`.

Les muestro un ejemplo:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Servicio
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" value="">
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Atendido" id="atendido">

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Lo que tengo hasta el momento es:

```
$(document).on("click", "#atendido", function(e){
    var aux;
    aux=$(this).parent().parent().parent();
    alert(aux);
});
```

pero aun no sé como llegar al `input` para obtener el valor del mismo, me estanqué.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Y no se te ha ocurrido utilizar un ID para eso?

Comment: es una tabla dinámica que se genera según una base de datos esta tabla se generara varias veces con datos diferentes

Comment: Y qué tiene eso que ver para asignarles ids únicos?

Comment: Ya te digo que lo que quieres hacer es una chapuza, cualquier solución que pase por hacer... parent.parent.parent.. no tiene sentido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma en la que puedes accesar al `input` que quieres es la siguiente, no sé si sea obligatoria la estructura que tienes pero podrías reestructurarla para que sea más fácil.

```js
$("#atendido").on("click", function(e) {
  var valor = $(this).closest("tr").prev().find("input").val();
  console.log(valor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Servicio</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" value="valor"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="Atendido" id="atendido"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: gracias es justo lo que andaba buscando

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", "#atendido", function(e){
    var aux;
    //2 parent() para ir hasta el tr | prev() para ir a la fila anterior | y find para buscar el input
    aux=$(this).parent().parent().prev().find("input").val();
    alert(aux);
});
```

Comment: Tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad. Sabes que se espera que la respuesta no sea solo un fragmento de codigo. por lo que se ve estas explicando dentro del codigo lo que haces. Podes ponerla un poco mas clara?